# Find numbers after last occurrence of keyword1 but still before keyword2

Tags: regex

Imaging the following multi-line text:

```
foo1
  some text
foo12
  some text
  bar
  some text
foo123
  some text
```

I want to find out to which *foo* belongs *bar*. In other words, I need to match only the numbers immediately after the last *foo* which still has *bar* after it.

In the example above the last *foo* meeting the condition is *foo12*, so I would like to match **12**.

I have almost no clue about regex and so far I got something like:

```
(?s)(?<=foo)\d*(?=.*bar)
```

You can check it out here:

https://regex101.com/r/FiwO14/1

It is matching the numbers after the first two *foo* (*foo1* and *foo12*), but I need just the second of them.

Comment: So why not just use the last match?

Comment: @CinCout. No special reason to be honest. After spending some time with it I was really curious about the "regex way" to do it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a `(?:(?!foo).)*?` [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970) in the lookahead:

```
(?s)(?<=foo)\d*(?=(?:(?!foo).)*?bar)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FiwO14/2)

The `(?:(?!foo).)*?` pattern matches any char (`.`), 0 or more times but as few as possible (`*?`), that is not a starting char of the `foo` sequence.

You may also write it as follows *if* the `foo`s are always at the start of a line:

```
(?<=foo)\d*(?=.*(?:\R(?!foo\d).*)*bar)
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FiwO14/3) (notice the absence of `(?s)` DOTALL modifier here, it is not necessary here). The `.*(?:\R(?!foo\d).*)*` matches:

- `.*` - the rest of the line
- `(?:\R(?!foo\d).*)*` - zero or more consecutive sequences of:

  - `\R(?!foo\d)` - any line break sequence (`\R`) that is not followed with `foo` and any digit
  - `.*` - the rest of the line.

Comment: Thank you Wiktor. I need to wait some minutes to accept the answer, but both solutions work perfectly. Thanks specially for including the explanation and the terminology.

Comment: Note that [unroll-the-loop approach](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop) (the second one) is much more efficient and should be preferred. A plain tempered greedy token is only good when we are lazy or when using a variable, or backreference.

Comment: Nice, I can see in *regex101* that it actually needs less steps to achieve it.

Comment: Yeah, but the number of steps is not actually a direct evidence that one regex is more efficient than another. In this case, sure, the second one will be more efficient because of the unroll-the-loop technique. Remember that a regex performance should only be checked in the target environment.